# Thunderbird 38.3.0 on Ubuntu 15.04 - Cannot connect to gmail server

Tags: firefox, internet, thunderbird, gmail, calendar

Linux LCP22 laptop, 64bit Ubuntu 15.04. Thunderbird 38.3 & Firefox 42.0 I am new to Ubuntu & command terminal use. 
My problem seemed to start around 20 Oct. Initially is seemed the problem was with Lightning Calendar not synchronizing with Google calendar & Android phone. 
Deleted TB profiles on numerous occasions, removed TB and reinstalled. Also removed and installed FF on a couple of occasions. That seemed to work for a day or two. 
Then cannot get emails when TB starts up or when trying to 'get mail'. This happened regularly although I tried creating new TB profiles.
I tried Evolution mail and that seemed to work but didn't like it and the calendar didn't synch with my phone. So reverted to TB. 
Updated TB & FF released a 3 weeks ago (+/- 25 Oct) and seemed to resolve this for a few days. Getting emails and calendar synching was working fine.

It's now started again. On starting TB 3 days ago, I am told it cannot connect to my various email accounts on Gmail. I can however see the accounts clearly on FF. Again deleted TB profiles and it worked. Same problem again today; TB cannot connect to server xyx@gmail.com.

I'd rather stick with TB as it does synchronise my calendars when it has an internet connection.  I tried attaching numerous images from the TB error Console to see if that may help someone understand my problem but can only post 2 images as I do not have enough reputation privileges. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[Error Console: Errors = Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYjP0.png) +
[Error Console: Errors = Image 2][2] +

@ Jos; thanks, \i don't know how that happened with the earlier images. Here's what I think should have been the 2nd image. [Error Console; Errors Image 2 corrected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Mr6.png)

20151118 Update

Starting FF today gave me a crash tab, a blank tab and a 'new' FF start page; (i.e. not what my normal preferences have been set at), I closed & restarted FF and that started fine but I had to reset all my preferences. All bookmarks etc were in place though.

On attempting to start TB, a pop-up / bubble told me TB was already running and I should close the current (running?) version and start a new window.

When I closed TB & FF yesterday, I used Ctrl +Q so I presume both were closed & not running. The laptop had been powered down for 8-9 hours.

As I could not close TB to start a new window, on a terminal, I started TB profile manager, selected the most recently created 'default' profile (all others having names such as 'old xyz date') and started TB from the profile manager. That now seems to be working ok, connecting to the gmail servers and synchronizing the calendars.

However, just tried to open a link from an email and got "Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system." I have had this numerous times in the last few weeks. Restarting the system doesn't seem to resolve the problem. A few days ago I 'refreshed' FF and that seemed to be ok.

Since updating from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04, I very often have a problem shutting down the laptop. On shutdown, it often restarts. On occasion I have had to force the shutdown. I wonder if perhaps TB & FF are still running 'in the background' and hence the problem? Any help would be appreciated.I don't want to go back to MS but am frustrated with these problems. Thanks.

**20151202 UPDATE**

Again deleted all profiles, removed and reinstalled both TB & FF. Started TB without any Lightning calendar add-on. Have run TB & FF for about 1 week without Lightning calendar and without any apparent problems. I've just seen an Ubuntu software centre update with TB + Calendar + Google add-on updates. I wonder if there was a problem with the calendar add-on & Google calendar synchronization. It appears so as I ran without calendar for a week without ant apparent problems. Will install & try new updated add-ons.

20151212 UPDATE

I've been running TB & FF without any apparent problems for 2-3 weeks. Someone on Mozilla forum suggested that the problem may be because I may have been running FF from Ubuntu and TB from Mozilla. That may have been the problem but since I deleted all profiles and reintsalled as above, still with FF ex Ubuntu and TB ex Mozilla, with Lightning Calendar addon, it all seems to be ok. My inexperienced perception is that at some stage, the TB ex Mozilla was reverting to a TB ex Ubuntu profile and hence the problem. Not sure if that is the case but that is what it seems. Hope this may help someone.

Comment: It's the same picture twice. However, I don't think the answer is in those screenshots.